# Как правильно написать слово "лабиринт" в тексте мифа о Тесее и Минотавре?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, ономастика

Как правильно написать слово "лабиринт" в тексте мифа о Тесее и Минотавре в школьном учебнике русского языка 5 класса. 
Вопрос авторов учебника и редактора

Answer (score 2):

С заглавной, думаю. Там это имя собственное.

Лопатин подтверждает: 
*лабиринт, -а (запутанная сеть ходов, помещений) и Лабиринт, -а (мифол.)*

Answer (score 0):

В мифе "Лабиринт" - это название дворца, поэтому пишется с заглавной буквы.